# How to type hint a particular dict type but allow empty dict in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, typing

I want to transfer data between different python-files. I create a new type so that different py-files all know what kind of data can be expected.

I used the following code.

```py
from typing import NewType

MyDataType = NewType("MyDataType", dict[str, dict[str, dict[str, dict[str, float]]]])


class App:
    def __init__(self, name: str, data: MyDataType):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data


app = App("app_1", data={}) # Pycharm warning: Expected type 'MyDataType', got 'dict' instead
```

However, PyCharm gives the warning:

```
Expected type 'MyDataType', got 'dict' instead
```

Basically, I want to make this `App.data` accept empty dict. Could you please show me how to do? Thanks!

Comment: The entire point of `NewType` is that it isn't compatible with underlying type and needs to be constructed explicitly. Either use `MyDataType({})`, or use a type alias instead of a `NewType`.

Comment: you don't want to use `NewType`, you just want a type alias. So `MyDataType = dict[str, ...]` In the most recent version, you should also probably type annotate the type alias! `MyDataType: typing.TypeAlias = dict[str, ...]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, would you like to write your suggestion as an answer? Then I can accept the solution. I like the idea of `TypeAlias`.

Comment: @aura I don't have the time right now, you are free to answer and accept your own questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give credit to @juanpa.arrivillaga and @Brian. Based on their comments, I write down the answer that solves my question so that it is easier for future readers.

Basically, it is not a good use case for `NewType`. Instead, `TypeAlias` is suitable. See the following code.

```py
from typing import TypeAlias

MyDataType: TypeAlias = dict[str, dict[str, dict[str, dict[str, float]]]]


class App:
    def __init__(self, name: str, data: MyDataType):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data


app = App("app_1", data={})
```